# Spring 4 STOMP over Websockets- How to setup login and passcode properly

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm playing around with Spring 4 Stomp over Websockets. Now I'm trying to put login and password in my configuration.

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        //registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
        //Enable MQ
        StompBrokerRelayRegistration relay=registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/");
        relay.setSystemLogin("login");
        relay.setSystemPasscode("passcode");
        //relay.setClientLogin("login");
        //relay.setClientPasscode("passcode");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

    }
```

But then when I try to connect with different login and passcode, I can still connect. Here's my javascript.

```
$scope.initSockets = function() {
        $scope.socket.client = new SockJS('/Html5GameApp');
        $scope.socket.stomp = Stomp.over($scope.socket.client);
        $scope.socket.stomp.connect("sample","sample",function(frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        $scope.socket.stomp.subscribe("/queue/stomp.data", $scope.liveGameData);
        });
        $scope.socket.client.onclose = $scope.reconnect;    
    };
```

Am I doing wrong with my configuration?How will I setup it properly.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is made of 3 "systems" or "actors" in this scenario:

- the browsers
- the Spring application
- the broker (e.g. RabbitMQ)

If you take a look at [StompBrokerRelayRegistration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/StompBrokerRelayRegistration.html)'s javadoc, you'll see that:

- **system credentials** are for the shared "system" connection and are used to send messages to the STOMP broker from within the application, i.e. messages not associated with a specific client session (e.g. REST/HTTP request handling method).
- **client credentials** are used when creating connections to the STOMP broker on behalf of connected clients.

If you're actually trying to enforce access security in your application, you could take a look at [the portfolio sample](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/) and [its security config](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/config/WebSecurityConfig.java). In a nutshell, security is enforced during the HTTP Upgrade phase in this example.